# Good books for Interpreter and Compiler using C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm planning to write a simple interpreter ( like TI-BASIC language for TI-89 ) or compiler ( C compiler ) using C++. I'm currently taking a course about programming languages, and learning the basic of BNF, EBNF. I wonder is it good enough to start on this project? In addition, could anyone know some good books about this area? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is a must read if you want to write a compiler.

Comment: 1+, yep it's considered to be part of the canon :)

Comment: I really need to buy that book.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder are there more books? Compiler and Interpreter are complex subjects, there are only couples books. That's really strange.

Comment: @Chan: I haven't read any other myself, this one covered my (admittedly not very complex) needs in the compiler department.

Comment: It's a serious subject for specialists, so less authors are tempted to write lousy books which won't sell.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone I know rants and raves about [Modern Compiler Construction in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521607655), although the Java version usually gets more credit. However if you want a more C++ focused book you can't go wrong with [Writing Compiler and Interpreters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471113530).

Comment: Thank you. I'll check them out.